# Change middle mouse button function in Windows

Tags: windows-7, mouse

Is there a way to assign a function (like cut/copy/paste) to the middle mouse button or scroll wheel in Windows 7?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try [X-Mouse](http://download.cnet.com/X-Mouse-Button-Control/3000-20432_4-75362562.html)!

> X-Mouse Button Control is a windows application to remap your mouse
>   buttons. This software can handle, including things like copy, cut,
>   and paste, volume control, media player control, send a custom
>   keystroke sequence, launch your email (or any other) application,
>   capture screen (or active window) image to clipboard, click-drag, and
>   save and restore desktop icon positions.

Comment: download from authors website http://www.highrez.co.uk/downloads/XMouseButtonControl.htm works with windows 10

Answer (score 8):

Out of the box, no, the mouse button is used for putting the machine in scroll mode.  If you have a Microsoft or Logitech mouse, there is some driver software (eg Intellipoint) that allows greater customization of the mouse buttons (including middle scroll button).

You can however find software (usually free) that gives you some of this functionality.  The most popular of these is: X Mouse Button Control: http://www.highrez.co.uk/downloads/XMouseButtonControl.htm

Answer (score 5):

Another possibility is to use [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) and assign the middle button to the action you want to perform. The example below sends a "back" signal when on a web page (to visit the previous page)

```
; Wheel click = back on navigator
~MButton::Send {Browser_Back}
```

Comment: Is it possible to not go back if the middle button was clicked on a tab header to close the tab?

Comment: That's great. A bit complex to get into but seems powerful

Comment: Similarly with my Thinkpad TrackPoint I set the middle button to close programs be executing: `MButton Up::Send !{F4}`

Comment: @thorn: (sorry for the slight delay in my answer, I doubt that it is still useful :)) I do not think so - when using Spy Window (part of AHK) the tabs are not seen as anything special (just part of the general browser window).